# The meaning of brackets around register in PTX assembly loads/stores

Tags: assembly, cuda, nvidia, ptx, triton

Below is an apparently legitimate PTX assembly code produced by [Triton compiler](https://github.com/openai/triton). I'm puzzled by `{ %r1 }` and `{ %r2 }` used in load and store instructions. According to the PTX ISA documentation, it looks like an [initializer list](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#initializers). But it does not make sense. Not only because initializers spec does not mention the use of registers. Not even because initializers within the load/store semantics are useless (there is nothing to initialize). Most of all I'm confused by the fact that the use of `{}` in loads/stores changes the meaning of argument from scalar to pointer immediate.

Perhaps, a bored dev just wanted to make everyone's assembly experience more confusing. Does anyone have any better explanation?

```
.version 7.5
.target sm_35
.address_size 64

        // .globl       E__01

.visible .entry E__01(
        .param .u64 E__01_param_0,
        .param .u64 E__01_param_1
)
.maxntid 128, 1, 1
{
        .reg .pred      %p<3>;
        .reg .b32       %r<4>;
        .reg .b64       %rd<3>;
        .loc    1 6 0
$L__func_begin0:
        .loc    1 6 0

        ld.param.u64    %rd2, [E__01_param_0];
        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [E__01_param_1];
        mov.pred        %p1, -1;
$L__tmp0:
        .loc    1 7 19
        mov.u32 %r1, 0x0;
        @%p1 ld.global.b32 { %r1 }, [ %rd1 + 0 ];
        .loc    1 8 18
        shl.b32         %r2, %r1, 1;
        .loc    1 9 22
        mov.u32         %r3, %tid.x;
        setp.eq.s32     %p2, %r3, 0;
        @%p2 st.global.b32 [ %rd2 + 0 ], { %r2 };
        .loc    1 9 2
        ret;
$L__tmp1:
$L__func_end0:

}
```

Comment: It's also used for vector operands, see [6.4.3. Vectors as Operands](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#vectors-as-operands). I guess the compiler just treats every scalar as a 1-element vector?

Comment: @Homer512: that's my guess also -- it is treated as a single element vector unpack. It might be that they try to use `{}` for all memory loads and stores whether  vector or scalar

Comment: @talonmies Is a vector argument valid for load/store operations?

Comment: Of course. CUDA has vector types and vector width memory transaction instructions

Comment: @talonmies I'm confused. There are vector types, which are supported with the special .v2 and .v4 suffixes of load/store operations. So an operation should explicitly denote when it works with vectors. In our case, .v2 or .v4 suffix is not present.

Comment: Think of a scalar transaction  with `{}` as being the implicit equivalent of `.v1 ` (which doesn’t actually exist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax seems to be a valid generalization of *load vector and unpack* or *pack vector and store*. Basically it treats a single register as a vector of size 1.

The same syntax with a proper vector can be seen in an example like this:

```
__global__ void foo(float2* arr, int n) {
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < n) {
        float2 x = arr[tid];
        arr[tid] = make_float2(x.x * x.y, x.x + x.y);
    }
}
```

The inside of that `if` compiles to

```
        ld.global.v2.f32        {%f1, %f2}, [%rd4];
        mul.f32         %f3, %f1, %f2;
        add.f32         %f4, %f1, %f2;
        st.global.v2.f32        [%rd4], {%f3, %f4};
```